# How to show last message from other user?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In the drop-down menu in the Facebook header, the last message for the member will be fetched
How does this system work? I have a code that does something like that, but the problem is that it brings the first message to the member and not the last message
How can the code be modified so that it brings the last message to the member?

```
<?php
$stmt = $db->prepare('select * FROM messages WHERE recipient_id = ?  GROUP BY sender_id ORDER BY id DESC');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['id']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo '<div class="div_messages"><a href="index.php?to='.$row['sender_id'].'"> message  <br />'.$row['sender_name'].'<br />'.$row['date'].'</a></div>' ;}
$stmt->close();
?>
```

Comment: Show sample data and expected result please

Comment: P.s. I would expect that Facebook's implementation is probably completely irrelevant to your question. They are likely to have an entirely different data structure and back end code. So while the outcome might seem similar, the way of getting there is totally different.

Comment: Change the order to ASC I think?, I'm not getting your question, which drop-down menu? because in my Facebook I see just my profile in that menu :S or are you talking about notifications? or messages in Messenger? If it's about messenger you can just play with the ORDER BY and that's it, and also maybe limit it to "LIMIT 10" or something like that so you don't show 132312 messages and instead only 10 and add "infinite scroll" to get more.

Comment: @Asfo I think it's more subtle than that. I suspect the grouping has something to do with the issue...but as I said above we need some sample data. Speculation and guesswork is rarely a productive pursuit for programmers.

Comment: Yep, just speculation, even ASC doesn't works I think because is the "old to new" instead of "new to old" which is DESC, so don't get it what that is happening too much, just trying to figure it out.

Comment: All I want is just to modify the code to show the most recent message instead of the first message

Comment: Yes. We know. So please help us to help you by providing the information requested. That we can we actually understand your situation fully and be able to suggest a solution

Comment: Yes - I made some adjustments and it worked well, thanks   $stmt = $db->prepare('select * from(select * FROM messages WHERE recipient_id =? GROUP BY id DESC) as T GROUP BY T.sender_id ORDER BY id DESC');

Comment: If you found the solution that's great but please post it below in the Answers then it's findable by people in future with a similar issue. Comments are not searchable, nor can they get meaningful upvotes. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes - I made some adjustments and it worked well

```html
$stmt = $db->prepare('select * from(select * FROM messages WHERE recipient_id =? GROUP BY id DESC) as T GROUP BY T.sender_id ORDER BY id DESC');
```